# OpenURL with refresh in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I am using  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url) to open a page in Safari.It is working fine , as far as opening the url in safari is concerned. But the problem is if that page is already opened in the safari and I call openURl method it just open that old page, not refreshing the content. I want to refresh it every time whenever I call opneURL . How to do that. ?

Comment: A possible easy solution, if you can, is implement a SFSafariViewController and open your URL within the app. At this stage you can control it like a UIWebView.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/38395653/3307233

Comment: No I can not use the SFSafariViewController , client wants to open it in safari.

Comment: Try opening the URI in private mode. Hope it will work.

Comment: Can I do this programatically or user has to do manually ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it possible to refresh a page in Safari.

You could try this:

```
func showTutorial(url : String) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: url) {
        let vc = SFSafariViewController(URL: url, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
        presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Please also read this:

[Refresh Safari page with openURL:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395104/refresh-safari-page-with-openurl)